np.unique after np.round unrounds the data
This code snippet describes a problem I have been having. For some reason rounded_data seems to be rounded, but once passed in np.unique and np.column_stack the result_array seems to be unrounded, meanwhile the rounded_data is still rounded.
rounded_data = data_with_target_label.round(decimals=2)

unique_values, counts = np.unique(rounded_data, return_counts=True)
result_array = np.column_stack((unique_values, counts))

print(rounded_data)
print(result_array)

Result:
443392    0.01
443393    0.00
443394    0.00
443395    0.00
443396    0.11
          ... 
452237    0.04
452238    0.00
452239    0.00
452240    0.00
452241    0.00
Name: values, Length: 8850, dtype: float32
[[0.00000000e+00 4.80000000e+01]
 [9.99999978e-03 2.10000000e+01]
 [1.99999996e-02 1.10000000e+01]
 ...
 [3.29000015e+01 1.00000000e+00]
 [3.94099998e+01 1.00000000e+00]


What are unique_values - without the joined counts?  column_stack makes a 2d array of floats, some much larger than the others.

What's rounded_data showing?  A column of a dataframe with indices?

@hpaulj yes, it's from a dataframe

Potentially there are several issues here.  float32/float64 for the rounded_data.  Whether unque changes them - unique is numpy, and thus sorts the array version of the Series.  Then how the floats will be combined with the integer counts in the column_stack.  And finally, how the 2d array of floats will be displayed - scientific notation is default for wide enough range of values.

this is because your dataframe is in float32 while default number format in numpy is float64. So the number that is rounded in float32 won't be visibly rounded in float64, because number representation is a bit different.
Solution is to convert either input array to float64 or the result_array into float 32.
Solution 1
Converting numpy array to float32:
rounded_data = data_with_target_label.round(decimals=2)

unique_values, counts = np.unique(rounded_data, return_counts=True)
result_array = np.column_stack((unique_values, counts))

result_array = np.float32(result_array)

Solution 2
Converting input data. For example input is pd.DataFrame (or pd.Series):
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': np.array([0.013242, 
                                     3.94099998, 
                                     9.99999978, 
                                     0.03234, 
                                     0.05532, 
                                     33.22, 
                                     33.44, 
                                     55.66])}, dtype = 'float32')


rounded_data = df['vals'].astype('float64').round(decimals=2)

unique_values, counts = np.unique(rounded_data, return_counts=True)

result_array = np.column_stack((unique_values, counts))


Thanks! Tried Solution 2 and seems to solve the problem.
Didn't think number format would be the problem here
